# Which fields have to be {braced} or "quoted" in .bib files (why does year NOT have to be)?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, brackets, braces

I'm writing some software for interacting with .bib fields. I want to be able to expand @string abbreviations in field values correctly, and I've been learning about quoting rules. In almost all cases, it seems that a field's value (the bit after the `=`) must:

- be entirely "quoted" or {braced}
- or be unbraced, but be the label for a `@string` abbreviation (to which the value will expand when cited)
- or consist of a `#` separated list of items, each of which conforms to one of the above bullets.

This is true, for example, of the `publisher` field. I couldn't compile a document with a citation to an entry including `publisher = Oxford University Press,`. It *doesn't* seem to apply to `year` though. `year = 2011,` works fine, as does `year = yr`, where I have `@String{yr = 1967}` (note lack of braces or quotes in the string definition).

Why is this? As far as I can tell from the docs, both are literal fields. How is the year field different, and what rules should my software implement? (Obviously I don't need a complete breakdown if you can point me at the relevant section of some docs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A great documentation for everything BibTeX is [Nicolas Markey's *Tame the BeaST*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). (The more official documentation at https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex is a bit lacking for most because it assumes knowledge of the LaTeX book [Leslie Lamport. LaTeX: A Document Preparation System. Addison-Wesley, 1997.])

In part 3, §8 *Structure of the `.bib` file* (p. 20) we find

> - Values (*i.e.* right hand sides of each assignment) can be either between curly braces or between double quotes. The main difference is that you can write double quotes in the first case, and not in the second case. For citing *Comments on “Filenames and Fonts”* by Frank Mittelbach,
>   you can use one of the following solutions:
>
>   ```
>   title = "Comments on {"}Filenames and Fonts{"}",
>   title = {Comments on "Filenames and Fonts"},
>   ```
>
>   Curly braces have to match, since they will appear in the output to be compiled by LaTeX. [...]
> - For numerical values, curly braces and double quotes can be omitted.

This means that the reason why you can omit the bracing/quoting in `year = 1994,` is because the value is purely numeric. This does not have to do with the specific field, it has to do with the contents.

The case of `@string`s is discussed in pt. 3, §9 on p. 21.